# Why can I read from STDOUT and get a user's terminal input?

Tags: c, linux

I'm perplexed. Under OSX and Linux (using BASH, TCSH, FISH, and DASH) this code successfully reads user input when that input is provided directly through the terminal but not when the user input is provided through a pipe.

Even more perplexing though: I don't expect this code to work at all! This code is READING from STDOUT. I'd expect the read call to return an error since I'm essentially reading from a write only pipe.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char buffer[11];
  size_t nread;
  if((nread=read(1, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1)) <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error!\n");
    return 1;
  }
  buffer[nread] = '\0';
  printf("I read '%s'\n", buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

To build (assuming you named the sample test.c):

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
```

Then, this reads the user input:

```
$ ./test
abcd
I read 'abcd

'
```

But, this does not:

```
$ echo "abcd" | ./test
<< program still waiting for the read to finish
```

Any insights?

Comment: Two things: You don't really terminate the string you read correctly. And *read* from `stdout`? Don't you mean `stdin`?

Comment: Also, `read` returns `-1` on error, and `0` on "file closed".

Comment: I fixed the null termination and the incorrect read error checking. The reason I'm perplexed is that this code works at all given that I am reading from stdout. I don't expect this code to "work" and yet it does!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminal implements `stdin` and `stdout` as the same read/write pseudo terminal and the two descriptors both map to the same thing by default. However, when you use a pipe the shell creates an actual pipe with distinct read and write ends, the read-end of which replaces the `stdin` of your program but not the `stdout`. Thus you cannot read the pipe's input from `stdout`, which is no longer the same thing as `stdin`.

Here's a little test showing what happens to the descriptors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main (void) {
    struct stat st;
    (void) fstat(0, &st);
    (void) printf("stdin  dev=%ld node=%ld\n", (long) st.st_dev, (long) st.st_ino);
    (void) fstat(1, &st);
    (void) printf("stdout dev=%ld node=%ld\n", (long) st.st_dev, (long) st.st_ino);
    return 0;
}
```

And when run:

```
$ ./fdcheck
stdin  dev=389931976 node=4338
stdout dev=389931976 node=4338
$ echo foo | ./fdcheck
stdin  dev=0 node=-5077412903630272353
stdout dev=389931976 node=4338
```

Under Linux you can also do:

```
$ readlink /proc/self/fd/0
/dev/pts/4
$ echo foo | readlink /proc/self/fd/0
pipe:[353335]
$ echo foo | readlink /proc/self/fd/1
/dev/pts/4
```

Comment: Fascinating! I'm still surprised that so many different shells exhibit the same behavior but this is a plausible explanation that includes proof that STDIN and STOUT map to the object under the conditions described.

Comment: @Brian The behaviour is so universal because the terminal's stdin and stdout tend to be the same pseudo terminal (e.g., `/dev/pts/*` or `/dev/pty*`). I edited the answer to show this more clearly under Linux.

Comment: (This means that the same also works in reverse: if the _output_ is redirected somewhere other than the terminal but the input is not, you can _write_ to `stdin` and it will appear in the terminal…)

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this is working, because on a terminal the `stdin` and `stdout` may point to the same object. That this is not correct behaviour you can see when you use pipes, because the output buffer should't be really provide data when read from. So this is maybe some bug or a sideeffect in the implementation of the terminal.

Comment: That was my original thought so I expanded my test set. I see the same behavior under OSX and Linux and using BASH, TCSH, FISH, and DASH as shells. I haven't actually found a combination for which my example doesn't have the described behavior.

Comment: To make sure you can check the code of the terminal, I wouldn't be surprised if you find the answer there. Nevertheless it would be undefined behaviour.